# How to get URL and its parameter value in F#

Tags: f#, websharper

Is there any way to get URL and further its parameter values in f# Only F# any one can help me. I have tried a lot but no solution found

http://www.example.com/blog?blogid=23

Want to get http://www.example.com/blog?blogid=23

Then 23

Comment: What is it that you want to accomplish exactly? Do you want to extract the scheme, host, port number, query string etc. from the URL or what?

Comment: Is there any way to get URL and further its parameter values in f# Only F# any one can help me. I have tried a lot but no solution found

http://www.example.com/blog?blogid=23

Want to get http://www.example.com/blog?blogid=23

Comment: Only want to extract 23 against blogid in F# code only please

Comment: I see you tagged websharper. Is this for client-side code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
let uri = new System.Uri("http://www.example.com/blog?blogid=23")
let blogId = uri.Query.Split('=').[1]
```

Comment: I have to get http://www.example.com/blog?blogid=23 value from address bar also it is not fixed but in address bar

Answer (score 3):

```
let getBlogId uriString =
    let uri = System.Uri(uriString)
    let kvps = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString uri.Query
    let idStr = kvps.["blogid"]
    int idStr
```

Comment: Very good but I have to get example.com/blog?blogid=23 value from address bar also it is not fixed but in address bar